# VBA: Transfer Data from Excel row to specific cells in another workbook, save as and loop to next row.

Tags: excel, vba

A client has asked us to generate reports by copy & pasting data from an excel row to their specified template (also in excel). This is required for all entries in the extract data they have provided.

So the loop would be:

1. Open Blank copy of Workbook B
2. Copy data from workbook A (where the code is hosted)
3. Paste the data into the specified cells in workbook B
4. Save Workbook B using Cell A1 as the file name
5. Close Workbook B
6. Proceed to next row of workbook A and repeat.

This is currently what I have written up, it clearly doesn't even get close to what I want it to do but so far the research I have done has only confused me more!

(Please forgive the "sheetname" etc in the middle, I had attempted to use sections of a previous code of mine here and I realised it wasn't going to work about half way through)

```
Sub Transfer()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim strpath As String
Dim strfolderpath As String
Dim z As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("c:\desktop\client data\export.xls")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("c:\desktop\client data\output template.xls")

' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
  NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  ' Select cell a1.
  Range("A1").Select
  ' Set loop
  For z = 1 To NumRows

                    'copy data from x:
                    x.Sheets("name of copying sheet").Range("E6").Copy

                    'paste to y worksheet:
                    y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("C1").PasteSpecial

                    'copy data from x:
                    x.Sheets("name of copying sheet").Range("E7").Copy

                    'paste to y worksheet:
                    y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("F7").PasteSpecial

                    'copy data from x:
                    x.Sheets("name of copying sheet").Range("E8").Copy

                    'paste to y worksheet:
                    y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

                    'save new worksheet

                        ' Save filename based on cell value

                             strfolderpath = "C:\"
                             strpath = strfolderpath & _
                                y.Sheets("").Range("A1").Value & " Report" & ".xlsx"

                            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strpath

        ' Selects cell down 1 row.
             ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

I look forward to expanding my VBA knowledge with your assistance.

Regards,

Matthew

Comment: Since you are copying a single cell, you can start by not copy pasting but assigning. ie. Sheet1.Range("A1").value = Sheet2.Range("A1").value

Comment: So what is wrong with the result?

Comment: also, please confirm, it's three workbooks that you have, one that has the vba code, another one that has the source data and a third one that should have the destination data

Comment: in addition, your loop doesn't do what is intended to do, the counter z, is not being used anywhere

Comment: @SNicolaou thank you for the pointer, that certainly helps tidy up the mess in the middle. Second point, I guess there's no need for there to be an additional workbook to host the code, I could easily just host it in the workbook where the data is coming from. An amusing over sight by myself.

Comment: then it mean you don't need to open workbook x, it would be already open right?

Comment: @McBern I have no idea how to make the code move the initial ranges down each time the loop occurs. So say the first time it does A1, how do I make the loop move that range to A2 and so on.

Comment: @SNicolaou that would be correct, yes. So I would only need to open workbook Y each time I perform the loop...?

Comment: so you want to create one file per row or do you want to create one file that has all rows?

Comment: @SNicolaou It would be one file per row. Each row contains a clients name and the relevant information associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

accroding to your comments then this is something that might work.
you need to adjust the sheet names and the cells(row, column) where the values are coming from.

NOTE, IT HAS NOT BEEN TESTED.

```
Sub Transfer()

  Dim sourceDataWb As Workbook
  Dim destinationDataWb As Workbook
  Dim strpath As String
  Dim strfolderpath As String
  Dim numberOfRows As Long, z As Long

  On Error GoTo error_catch

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  '## Open both workbooks first:
  Set sourceDataWb = ActiveWorkbook

  numberOfRows = sourceDataWb.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

  For z = 1 To numberOfRows
    ' OPEN
    Set destinationDataWb = Workbooks.Open("c:\desktop\client data\output template.xls")
    ' COPY AS NECESSARY
    destinationDataWb.Sheets("sheetname").Cells(z, 1).Value = sourceDataWb.Sheets("sheetname").Cells(z, 1).Value
    ' CREATE THE PATH
    strpath = "C:\" & destinationDataWb.Sheets("sheetname").Range("A1").Value & " Report" & ".xlsx"
    ' SAVE
    destinationDataWb.SaveAs Filename:=strpath
    destinationDataWb.close
    'REPEAT
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Exit Sub

error_catch:
  MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
  Err.Clear
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: also, check where the name for the new workbook is coming from, i have it to come somewhere in the destinationDataWb, but perhaps the value is in the sourceDataWb.

Comment: Good Morning. Apologies for the delay in responding here.

Currently attempting to run the code results in an error message with "error: object doesn't support this property or method". 

This seems to be caused by 

  Set destinationDataWb = Workbooks.Open  line. 

I have confirmed that using just workbooks.open works as intended.

Comment: as i said, the code was untested but glad to see that you managed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just modify a bit your orignal code:

```
Sub Transfer()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim strpath As String
Dim strfolderpath As String
Dim z As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("c:\desktop\client data\export.xls")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("c:\desktop\client data\output template.xls")

x.Sheets("name of copying sheet").activate

' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
  NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  ' Select cell a1.
  Range("A1").Select
  ' Set loop
  For z = 1 To NumRows

                    'copy data from x:
                    x.Sheets("name of copying sheet").Cells(z,5).Copy 'E6

                    'paste to y worksheet:
                    y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("C1").PasteSpecial

                    'copy data from x:
                    x.Sheets("name of copying sheet").Cells(z+1,5).Copy 'E7

                    'paste to y worksheet:
                    y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("F7").PasteSpecial

                    'copy data from x:
                    x.Sheets("name of copying sheet").Cells(z+2,5).Copy 'E8

                    'paste to y worksheet:
                    y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

                    'save new worksheet

                        ' Save filename based on cell value

                             strfolderpath = "C:\"
                             strpath = strfolderpath & _
                                y.Sheets("").Range("A1").Value & " Report" & ".xlsx"

                            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strpath

        ' Selects cell down 1 row.
             'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
         z = z+2
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```